# Typescript error "Cannot find name 'require'. and Cannot find name 'process'."

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

Typescript error "Cannot find name 'require'. and Cannot find name 'process'." even when it already has defined the parameter **"moduleResolution": "node"** into its compiler options.

The following is my current tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es2015",
     "lib": ["es2015", "es6"],
     "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "rootDir": "src",
     "outDir": "./build",
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "declaration": false
  },
  "include": [
     "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
     "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Type definitions for the Node.js standard library are not bundled by default. You need to install them yourself via the `@types/node` package:

```
npm install --save @types/node
```

The `moduleResolution` option controls [how the compiler handles import statements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), and has nothing to do with the Node.js standard library.

To fix the "Cannot find name 'require'" errors, you should also convert any CommonJS imports to use TypeScript import syntax:

```
// Before
var process = require('process');

// After
import process = require('process');
```

See the [Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#importing-from-modules) section of the TypeScript handbook for details.

Answer (score 4):

For me it is resolved by adding **types** to the angular compiler options in angular 8.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
"strictInjectionParameters": true,
"types": [ "node" ]
}
```